# Taking product of cofactor with different row

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given a matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, let $C_{i,j}$ be the cofactor in position $(i,j)$. By the determinant formula, we have

$$\det A=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,1}C_{i,1}.$$

What about if we take a different column for the cofactors, that is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,1}C_{i,2}$$

Must this evaluate to zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the expansion of the cofactor with a different row (or analagously, column) will always produce zero. To see why, consider the cofactor expansion along the $k$th row
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}C_{kj}.$$
Notice that each of the cofactors $C_{kj}$ has no knowledge of the the entries of the $k$th row. By definition, the cofactors of the $k$th row do not depend on the $k$th row. Therefore we can view the expansion along the entries of some other row, say row $k' \neq k$, given by 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{k'j}C_{kj},$$
as replacing the entries of the $k$th row by those of the $k'$th row. In effect, the expansion now thinks that row $k$ and row $k'$ of the matrix are equal, and consequently evaluates to zero.

Comment: _In effect, the expansion now thinks that row k and row k′ of the matrix are equal, and consequently evaluates to zero._ Can you please explain this? I'm having trouble understading it.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Remember that the cofactors $C_{kj}$ doesn't know about the entries of row $k$. They only enter the cofactor expansion through the coefficients $a_{kj}$ explicitly in the sum. So if we replace $a_{kj}$ with $a_{k'j}$, that's the same as performing a cofactor expansion of the matrix with row $k'$ in place of $k$. Since the determinant is always zero for matrices with a row repeated, it will necessarily evaluate to zero here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Proof by construction: take a matrix $A$. Make another matrix $B$ by copying $A$'s first row to second row (in effect throwing away $A$'s second row).

Now, determinant of $B$ can be equivalently written as sum of pairwise multiplication of $B$'s second row with cofactors of elements of first row (since first and second rows are identical). Also, $\vert B \vert = 0$ since first and second rows are linearly depenedent.

Thus the statement follows.