# Equation containing cofactor of derivative and Kronecker-delta

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, kronecker-delta

Let $d_{ij}$ be the cofactor of $\frac{\partial f_j(x)}{\partial x_i}$ in $J_f(x)$, i.e. $d_{ij}$ is $(-1)^{i+j}$ times the determinant which you obtain from $J_f(x)$ cancelling the $j$-th row and the $i$-th column. 
Let $J_f(x)$ be the Jacobian matrix and $\delta_{ij}$ the Kronecker-delta. Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n d_{ij}(x) \frac {\partial f_k(x)}{\partial x_i} = \delta_{jk} ~ det ~ J_f(x), ~~~\text{for}~~j,k \in \{1,..,n\}
\end{align}

My questions is, why the equation is accurate. In particular I don't see why the left side should be zero, if $j \neq k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Jacobians, it holds for any matrix.

If $j=k$, it's just expansion of the determinant along the $j$th row. And if $j \neq k$, it's “expansion along the wrong row”, where you expand along one row but use the cofactors from another row, which gives the same result as if you do expansion of a determinant where two rows are equal, i.e., the result is zero.

Comment: Thank you! I fully undestand the $j=k$ case. 
As for the $j \neq k$ I tried it with a general $3 \times 3$-matrix and got zero as a result. However I don't see why this holds for every dimension/ why if you expand along one row and use the cofactors from another row, it's the same as if you calculate the determinant of a linearly independant matrix.

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845054/taking-product-of-cofactor-with-different-row?